# MySQL Select table header Union with query result gives Error Code: 1250. Table from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in global ORDER clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following 2 tables:

`tableA`

```
ID  name  link
1   A1    example.com  
2   A2    example2.com
3   A3    example3.com
```

`tableB`

```
ID  name  score
1   A1    68  
2   A2    345
3   A3    12
```

Now I need to extract to csv as follow:

```
SELECT 'ID', 'name', 'link', 'score'
UNION
SELECT tabA.*, tabB.score from tableA tabA, tableB tabB
where tabA.ID = tabB.ID 
and tabA.name = tabB.name  
order by tabA.ID ASC, tabB.score DESC
INTO OUTFILE 'result.csv'
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Basically, I want all columns in `tableA` and column `score` in `tableB` where both `ID` and `name` match. And the result is sorted by column `ID` and then `score`. I got the below error:

> Error Code: 1250. Table 'tabA' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in global ORDER clause

From other answers, I think I need to use subquery or table alias but I can't seem to come up with the correct syntax to also include the table headers. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend something like this:

```
SELECT id, name, link, score
FROM ((SELECT 'ID' as id, 'name' as name, 'link' as link, 'score' as score, 1 as which
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT a.id, a.name, a.link, b.score, 2 as which
       FROM tableA a JOIN
            tableB b
            ON a.ID = b.ID AND
               a.name = b.name  
      )
     ) ab
ORDER BY which, ID ASC, score DESC;
```

Note:  This assumes that the types of the columns are all strings.  If not, you will need to convert them, presumably something like:

```
SELECT id, name, link, score
FROM ((SELECT 'ID' as id, 'name' as name, 'link' as link, 'score' as score, 1 as which
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT CAST(a.id as CHAR), a.name, a.link, CAST(b.score as CHAR), 2 as which
       FROM tableA a JOIN
            tableB b
            ON a.ID = b.ID AND
               a.name = b.name  
      )
     ) ab
ORDER BY which, ID + 0 ASC, score + 0 DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you. That works! Minor question: my `score` column is actually `FLOAT`. I got a warning `1 warning(s): 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'score'`. But the result still shows correct decimal numbers. Is this significant?

Comment: @hydradon . . . Not a major problem, but you should probably convert the value to a string in the second subquery.